# SELECT query with multiple AND

Tags: php

Good day. I want to check my database if it has a row that contains three variables that I assigned:

I used this script and it's not giving the result that I want.

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name`
WHERE `field1`='$var1'
AND `field2`='$var2'
AND `field3`='$var3'
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Probably because there are no records that satisfy all 3 conditions? Your query has a correct syntax

Comment: print your query for debugging

Comment: Doesnt seem like there would be an error. What is in your table and whats your query? Use echo to print your query. #query = 'Select .....'; echo $query;

Comment: What do you mean by `has a column that contains three variables` ?

Comment: Yes use mysql_quey($query) or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with the query but check if something is wrong with the table by using

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `table_name`
WHERE `field1`='$var1'
AND `field2`='$var2'
AND `field3`='$var3'";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thanks. I am so tired, I've been doing my project for almost 8 hours without resting, and I found out that my error is a closing parenthesis. I am using notepad ++, and it's not able to give me my syntax error. Woa. Thanks.